# Render Roads in QGIS using z-order like in OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, symbology, cartography

I am using QGIS with OpenStreetMap data and I am trying to copy the way OpenStreetMap renders the order of their roads using the 'z-order' field. I am very close, I managed to use the layer properties to blend the roads where they join together using 'symbol levels' in the Symbology tab:

[image]

However, where roads are elevated over other roads I want it to look like the picture below in OpenStreetMap. I know they use the 'z-order' field and I know this can be done in QGIS using the 'control feature rendering order' option and choosing the z-order field, but I can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

The following are my layer symbol properties. I also checked 'Control feature rendering order' and used the z-order field:

[image]

I set my Symbol Levels as follows:

[image]

And I get the image below.

[image]

so I think I am close. I think the key may have something to do with the "bridge"=>"yes" tag in the Other_Tags attribute. Please see my new symbol properties above, I duplicated the symbols so one set has bridges and the other does not (LIKE and NOT LIKE). I then set the symbol levels so the "bridged" set renders above the "non-bridged" set. Plus, I checked 'Control feature rendering order' and used the z-order field. I also made the outer line flat as @mapperx recommended which helped. I was able to produce the last image above which I think is very close. However, you can see there are now "breaks" (circled red) where two segments join that both include the tags "bridge"=>"yes". This makes sense because of the way I setup the symbol levels. I have played with this for most of the day, but I can't for the life of me figure this out. I know it can be done because OpenStreetMap does it perfectly.

Comment: You need to set the symbol level order. If you look at the image showing Symbol properties above, there is the Symbol Levels option. You need to set a column/order attribute which defines how it will render.

Comment: Hi @mapperx, I added a couple more screenshots above. I set the Symbol Levels as shown above which seems to work, but there are breaks where the line segments join each other (see last image). Is there a way to get past that? I have tried so many different ways to render these correctly with no luck.

Comment: The breaks are a different issue. That has to do with the join style of/for each line category/group. Let me download some OSM data and make an answer so that i can add screenshots. Will do that in a bit.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: Hi @mapperx, thank you for your continued help. I updated some information in my original post and updated the images. Please see my note at the bottom of the original post. I know this can be done because OpenStreetMap does it perfectly. If you look closely at their map there are no breaks and each segment blends into the next.

Comment: Which categories are those roads that you circled?

Comment: I have added some images and explanation can help you. Try to look at the relationship of the z_order and all the possible attributes which is used in styling each road group(highway class, other_tags conditions. There is no quick fix
Also this is my own approach, someone else my do it differently.

Comment: @mapperx, thank you for all your help! I used all your suggestions and ended up classifying by Type, then adding ranges to each type based on the z-order field (right-click the Type in Layer Properties, Refine Current Rule, Add Ranges to Rule). Then I set Symbol Levels for each z-order range so the lines would render over/under each other appropriately. I did not end up needing the 'Control feature rendering order' option. This gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again!

Comment: It was a learning process for me too. Happy mapping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is a z-order column in Openstreetmap data. You can use this in setting the rendering order. [**@das-g**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/51574/das-g) gave a good answer to a similar question *(the link is to the answer provided)* [***Applying OSM z-order after osm2pgsql with qgis***](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203771/49327). The answer gives a good explanation on how to go about. I will add some explanations and images that can help as well.

[image]

In the second image you attached, you need to enable **Symbol levels** and for each symbol adjust the number to set its hierarchy. This hierarchy determines the order of how each **Category** of line overlap
[image]
With regards to the lines having breaks, most of **osmdata** lines *(in this case I am referring to the roads)* are in segments. So a particular street might have multiple segments. You need to adjust the line **Cap Style**. This defines how the lines/segments ***end*** and ***overlap*** each other,(it also might depend on your line styling having outercase and innerline). I would use **Square** for the inner and **Flat** for the outer. There is also Round option depending on the style you want.
[image]

---

**Part 2**:- Based on your corrections and what you have done so far.

I tried to reproduce something similar. I have used a different approach to filter the road classes. Its should give you a rough idea.
[image]

From the screenshot of your Symbol level, you need to increase the values for each group depending on its hierarchy. The z-order will give you an idea of the value a line/road has. The higher the value the higher its hierarchy. That way the group can be raised accordingly.
[image]